# list creation from attribute in list of maps

Tags: terraform

I have the following list of maps:

```
variable "virtual_machines" {
  default = {
    "master1" = {
       name         = "z-ca-bdc-master1"
       worker_node  = false
       ipv4_address = "192.168.113.79"
       ipv4_netmask = "22"
       ipv4_gateway = "192.168.112.1"
       dns_server   = "192.168.112.2"
       ram          = 8192
       logical_cpu  = 4
       disk0_size   = 40
       disk1_size   = 0
    },
    "master2" =  {
       name         = "z-ca-bdc-master2"
       worker_node  = false
       ipv4_address = "192.168.113.80"
       ipv4_netmask = "22"
       ipv4_gateway = "192.168.112.1"
       dns_server   = "192.168.112.2"
       ram          = 8192
       logical_cpu  = 4
       disk0_size   = 40
       disk1_size   = 0
    },
```

What I would like to do is create a list of virtual machine names that I can assign to a variable, containing z-ca-bdc-master1, z-ca-bdc-master2 etc . . . how can I achieve this ?

My end goal is to be able to use this with template_file:

```
data "template_file" "k8s" {
  template = file("./templates/kubespray_inventory.tpl")

  vars = {
    k8s_master_host = values(var.virtual_machines)[*].name
    k8s_node_host   = values(var.virtual_machines)[*].name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the "list of virtual machine names" from your `var.virtual_machines` you can do:

```
locals {
   vm_names = values(var.virtual_machines)[*].name
}
```

Then you can use it when you need it as `local.vm_names`.

Update:

```
locals {
   vm_names = [for k,v in var.virtual_machines: v.name if v.worker_node]
}
```

Comment: Marcin - is there anyway to make this conditional, say only put a virtual machine name in the list if its associated worker_node attribute is true ?

Comment: @ChrisAdkin You can check the updated answer.

Comment: terraform plan gives me this when I try to use it template_file:

  on main.tf line 47, in data "template_file" "k8s":
  47:   vars = {
  48:     k8s_master_host = values(var.virtual_machines)[*].name
  49:     k8s_node_host   = values(var.virtual_machines)[*].name
  50:   }
    |----------------
    | var.virtual_machines is object with 5 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "vars": element "k8s_master_host": string
required.

Comment: I've added the temp_file code to the question with formatting.

Comment: @ChrisAdkin You can't pass any map nor list to `template_file`, so it fails. This version called [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) is more versatile. If you will have issue with the `templatefile` maybe its better to make new question.